# How to create a subdomain manually

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I want create a subdomain that is not possible to create on cPanel (the word "admin" is reserved by Hostinger), it is not in use and I want host my admin panel on this subdomain, I need create it by myself.
I have access to DNS recorder, but I don't know how redirect it to correct folder (same IP address for all). I created an A recorder on DNS, and it's return:

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.

I'm using CloudFlare.

Comment: The result clearly shows that the hostname you defined (sometimes incorrectly called "subdomain") _is_ actually resolved inside the DNS system. Otherwise you would get another error message. What is missing is the host definition inside the http server, apparently. I suggest you take a look at the config files, _if_ you have access to that. It might be though that the limited access cheap shared hosting providers offer their users simply does not allow such fine grained configuration.

Comment: I'm using shared hosting provider and I don't have access to config files :(. On PHP I can add my personal `php.ini` with a file named `.user.ini`. Can I do it in this case?

Comment: Your issue is not php, as far as I understood, but the configuration of the http server. Those are two completely separate things. Looks like you have to consult the documentation or support your hosting provider offers. That is what it is for and what you pay for.